# NT Server: deleting files takes ages

Tags: files, windows

i'm running an NT Server - when trying to delete eg. just one file - it takes several minutes (!!) until the file gets deleted. i'm only getting the deleting-dialog but nothing happens.

any ideas what could be wrong?

thx

Comment: Oh... yeah, other people are right: This question belongs on Superuser.com or Serverfault.com .

Comment: How big is the file, how much free space is there on the filesystem, and does it perform the same way when you try deleting it from the command line?

Comment: Have you tried checking the disk for errors?

Comment: NT Server? From which century? (ie which version) ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be caused by a very full recycle bin, or deleting files from a directory that has way too many files, or a fragmented MFT (especially in NT4.0 NTFS).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the problem is on a local disk, not network connection.

1) If you have some kind of real time antivirus protection, disable it and see if the problem persists

2) Do a CHKDSK on that file system

3) If you are deleting via Explorer interface, check the trashcan and try to delete file via CMD command line interface and see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's deleting into an already overfull garbage can. Try SHIFT-Delete!